# Is there an alternative to autowiring via constructor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I know that spring has deemed as a "bad practice" the usage of @Autowired and now you can inject via constructor:

```
private final Field f;

public MyClass(Field f){
   this.f = f;
}
```

But isn't there any other way? At the moment I have this class:

```
public abstract class MyClass{
     public MyClass(String s){
         ...
    }
}
```

And I don't want to make "public" the existence of f: if I used the constructor the caller should explicitely set it.
In this case @Autowired works better as it injects it seamelessy.

Comment: It is an `abstract` class, so the one extending it needs to know what the parent class needs (or provides). Don't hide those details for other classes. The fact that something looks easier doesn't mean it is better (it is actually hiding things and will lead to issues in writing a simple unit test as you need reflection to set the dependency for one thing).

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want to hide that there is a dependency?  Constructor injection is great for so many reasons, such has showing the bean-dependencies of a bean.  It's hard to imagine what benefits there could be in hiding the dependence